Get text and position of a button of an external by id
Hey I found an App which can get the Text and the position of a Button of any App.(See pictures)
The App is an Auto-Clicker.
App Screenshot
App Screenshot 2
App Screenshot 3
As seen in the pictures the App can highlight every button on the screen and show you the text and button id of the selected button.
I would like to build something similar my self. I just couldn't find anything related to this topic.
Has anyone any idea how to do this?  Thanks in advance.
